# How to burn an Audio DVD

Tags: dvd, flac, dvd-audio

I bought some 192KHZ, 24 Bit FLAC Files.

I would like to burn these to an audio DVD so I can play them through my Blu Ray player on my home system.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a waste of money to do that. 192 KHz, 24-bit FLAC files are lossless and very high quality, so get a 256GB USB 3.0 flash drive and copy/paste the FLAC files to a USB flash drive instead. FLAC files on USB flash drives produce a cleaner sound than DVDs without the DVD audio haze. A 192 KHz, 24-bit FLAC file also sounds better than a prerecorded audio CD when played in the same Blu-ray player. And unlike most DVDs USB flash drives are rewriteable without any loss in audio quality.

Keep the flash drive plugged in all the time in the Blu-ray's USB port so you can listen to the music that you copied onto the flash drive by using the Blu-ray player's remote control to navigate on-screen to the selected music file.

Comment: This answer was very helpful.